# How to set center of google map based on street address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, maps

I have just started working with the Google Maps API and Geocoding Service.  I followed  [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZE8ODPL2VPI)   tutorial and it was great.

Now I want to be able to create a map with a center based on a location ( "Vancvouer, BC" ) as opposed to latitude and longtitude as required when creating the map.

What I am trying to do is use a callback function named "initMap()" to initialize the map, and in that function I am creating a Geocoder object to get lang and long based on a location. ( "Vancvouer, BC" ).

Here's my initMap() function:

```
function initMap() {

    var geocoder1 = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var center = getCenter(geocoder1, 'Vancouver, BC');

    if(center != null) {
        alert(center[0].geometry.location);
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 8,
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
    });
}
```

This is how I am getting lang and long based on address:

```
function getCenter(geocoder, address) {
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(results);
            var result = results[0].geometry.location.toJSON();
            return result;
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            // return null;
        }
    });
}
```

This will return a JSON object with the lat and lang I want, but when I try to access its values in initMap() using the if statement center is always undefined.

Once I am able to get the value for center I believe I would be able to set the center easy enough, but why I am not getting these values?

I think its a problem with scope and callback functions, but cant figure it out.  Been stuck for a while, thought I'd reach out for help.

Thanks,

Matt

P.S. Let me know if you need any other info. First post on stackoverflow...

Comment: You need to wait for the geocoder to return the result. One option would be to call getCenter on page load, then pass the location to init. The better option would be just to figure out the coords of Vancouver and hard code them into init

Comment: I don't like the idea of hardcoding values in, the end goal for this is to try and make the center based on the users location(based on phone).  This might not require a string value to set center, but cannot be hardcoded.

Answer (score 3):

The geocoder is asynchronous, you can't return anything from an asynchronous callback function.  You need to use the returned data inside the callback function where/when it is available:

```
function setCenter(geocoder, address) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 8,
        center: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      // return null;
    }
  });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/h1zusmzb/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {

  var geocoder1 = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  setCenter(geocoder1, 'Vancouver, BC');
}

function setCenter(geocoder, address) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 8,
        center: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      // return null;
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! So, the problem was that my initMap() function was occurring asynchronously? So that function would run till completion before the results of the setCentre() function were returned so my "MapObject" was being created before the data was available? So you make the map within the same function that is making request for the data.  Right?

Comment: Your `initMap` function is inline, it isn't asynchronous.  The geocoder is asynchronous, its response comes back after the function that called it (`getCenter`) has completed, so the value is not available to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to convert the results to Json. Use

```
    center[0].geometry.location
```

This can be assigned to the **center** property of the map object. To check for null:

```
    if (center[0] != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Set center by address after map ini:**

example:

```
set_center(address)

function set_center(address) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      }
    })
  }
```

**var "map" must be ini with google map, example**

```
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('main-map'), mapOptions);
```